# How do I find out what resources googles security panel is referring to?

Tags: ssl, https

This is the image I see in googles security panel when hitting F12 when accessing the site that I am trying to develop. I have no idea how to fix this issue so that the site comes up as secure. How can I find what resources it is referring to?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that some of my images were not going through the SSL layer. I had to install Firefox dev edition and see what resources were causing the issues using Firebug. Once I fixed that, the site popped up as secure.